# equivalent deduction of Non-mechanical thermodynamic work

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-engineering

"Work (as in Thermodynamics) is said to be done by a system if sole effect on the surroundings could be the raising of a weight." So, how is non mechanical work like : Chemical work, Magnetization work or even electric current flow work be reduced to the same?

Comment: Do you mean a chemical reaction? ie fizz fizz bubble bubble ? What definition do you have for electric current? And, best yet, do permanent magnets loose power over time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other work is also a flow of energy between system and surroundings (across a boundary). Heat is flow of energy too. Consider these three sayings as analogous:

- Mechanical work is said to be done BY a system if the sole effect on the surroundings could be the raising of a weight (in the surroundings).
- Heat flow is said to be EXOTHERMIC if the sole effect on the surroundings could be an increase in the temperature of the surroundings.
- Other work is said to be done BY a system if the sole effect on the surroundings could be either the raising of a weight (in the surroundings) or an increase in the temperature of the surroundings.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. now it is clear to me.